# null object reference in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I am trying to work on radio groups. I have an **ok** button which when clicked selects one item from four inflated radio button groups. My problem is that, when the user does not select an option from one of the groups, I have a null pointer exception.

**Here is my selection code**

```
private void getSelectedValuesAdults()
{
    rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_selections);

    int id1 = ((RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.KSradioGrp)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    int id2 = ((RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.KTradioGrp)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    int id3 = ((RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.KDradioGrp)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    int id4 = ((RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.KSoradioGrp)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    stringChoice[0]= ((RadioButton)findViewById(id1)).getText().toString().contains(generalKid[0].getName())==true?generalKid[0].getName():generalKid[1].getName();      
    stringChoice[1]= ((RadioButton)findViewById(id2)).getText().toString().contains(generalKid[2].getName())==true?generalKid[2].getName():generalKid[3].getName();
    stringChoice[2]= ((RadioButton)findViewById(id3)).getText().toString().contains(generalKid[4].getName())==true?generalKid[4].getName():generalKid[5].getName();
    stringChoice[3]= ((RadioButton)findViewById(id4)).getText().toString().contains(generalKid[6].getName())==true?generalKid[6].getName():generalKid[7].getName();

    genCost[0]= ((RadioButton)findViewById(id1)).getText().toString().contains(generalKid[0].getName())==true?generalKid[0].getCost()+5:generalKid[1].getCost()+5;
    genCost[0]= ((RadioButton)findViewById(id2)).getText().toString().contains(generalKid[2].getName())==true?generalKid[2].getCost()+5:generalKid[3].getCost()+5;
    genCost[0]= ((RadioButton)findViewById(id3)).getText().toString().contains(generalKid[4].getName())==true?generalKid[4].getCost()+5:generalKid[5].getCost()+5;
    genCost[0]= ((RadioButton)findViewById(id4)).getText().toString().contains(generalKid[6].getName())==true?generalKid[6].getCost()+5:generalKid[7].getCost()+5;

}
```

The Ok button jumps to the method above. I have used `if(id1==-1||id2==-1||id3==-1||id4==-1) callDialogMessage()` just before the assignment to `stringChoice[0]` where `callDialogMessage()` is a message that lets you know you have not selected from a radio group but my app still crashes. What can I do? Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, and the [complete stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173).

Comment: before storing selected values in id1,id2,id3,id4 check if(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)

Answer (score 0):

On click of OK button get selected radio button Id using radio group .You can refer the below code.

```
     int selectedId =radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();;

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
     RadioButton radioButton = FindViewById<RadioButton>(selectedId);

     if(radioButton !=null)
      {
        //do things here
      }
```